# Finding the exact solutions for a system of equations

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, singular-solution

I am computationally trying to solve the system of linear equations given below.

$
\frac{1}{1+tan(\theta/2)*tan(\phi/2)*tan(\psi/2)} 
\begin{bmatrix}
tan(\psi/2)-tan(\theta/2)*tan(\phi/2) \\
tan(\phi/2)+tan(\theta/2)*tan(\psi/2) \\
tan(\theta/2)-tan(\phi/2)*tan(\psi/2)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
r_1 \\ r_2 \\ r_3
\end{bmatrix} 
$

I use the least square approximations to find the solution to this equation on MATLAB. However, no effective solution was found using this method. Considering that the system values for r1, r2, r3 and $\psi$ = 0 are known whereas $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the two unknown values. Is it possible to obtain exact solution for these two unknowns of the system for $r = [0,-0.101233861621737,0.365119069777688]$.

The values I obtain on solving this system is $\theta = 0.6950 $ and $\phi =  -0.1785$, Even-though these are good approximate values, I was wondering if it's possible to obtain the exact values using a different approach.

Comment: I'm confused. If $\psi = 0$ and $r_1 = 0$, the first equation tell us $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}\tan\frac{\phi}{2} = 0$. This is incompatible with your value of $\theta$, $\phi$ (none of them are close to multiples of $2\pi$  which one need to make tan(half-angle) to vanish)

Comment: @achillehui I think it's only the best approximated solution when I solve it numerically with least square approximations. It is clearly not the exact values that would satisfy the equation. This is what I want to figure out.

Comment: you mean $\psi$ need not equal to $0$ but determined by the relation: $\tan\frac{\psi}{2} = \tan\frac{\theta}{2}\tan\frac{\phi}{2}$

Comment: Yes, the value of  is just dependent on the values of  and , I assume.

Comment: Could you tell the origin of the problem, in particular the meaning of angles (Euler angles ? but for which configuration ?).

Comment: Replacing the tangents by unknowns, what you have is a system of three cubic equations. By eliminating two unknowns, you can end up with a high degree univariate polynomial. Good luck !

Comment: @JeanMarie The origin of the problem is related to converting rotation vector r into Fick's angles ,  and .

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: These formulas look explainable in terms of quaternions. See for example [this paper](https://rotations.berkeley.edu/geodesics-of-the-rotation-group-so3/) (although not directly connected to Fick's angles)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for the beautiful paper suggestion. I actually wanted to work on a reduced version of the quaternion for application in Listing's law. That is why I specifically chose the rotation vectors instead. I naturally set the first component of the rotation vector as zero for the specific application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $r_1 = 0, r_2, r_3 \ne 0$. Let $t_1 \tan\frac{\psi}{2}$, $t_2 = \tan\frac{\phi}{2}$
and $t_3 = \tan\frac{\theta}{2}$.

With help of a CAS, I get two set of solutions:
$$t_2 = \frac{s_2 - \epsilon \sqrt{s_2^2 - 4r_2^2}}{2r_2},\quad t_3 = \frac{s_3 + \epsilon \sqrt{s_3^2 + 4r_3^2}}{2r_3}\tag{*1}$$
where $\epsilon = \pm 1$ and $s_2 = r_2^2+r_3^2+1$, $s_3 = r_2^2+r_3^2-1$.

For $(r_1,r_2,r_3) = (0,−0.101233861621737,0.365119069777688)$, the approximation solution you get corresponds to the $\epsilon = +1$ solution. Numerically, the corresponding angles evaluated to

$$(\psi, \phi, \theta ) \sim
(-0.0657294323,-0.1779886273,0.7060269791)$$

The formula in $(*1)$ is relatively simple, it should be possible to derive that by hand. <strike>However, I can't figure that out yet</strike>. You can plug those expression to a CAS and verify that yourself.

**Update**

I sort of figure out how to derive the two solutions in $(*1)$.

When $r_1 = 0$, first equation give us $t_1 = t_2t_3$. Substitute this into second and third equation, we have

$$\frac{t_2(1+t_3^2)}{1 + t_2^2t_3^2} = r_2\quad\text{ and }\quad
\frac{t_3(1-t_2^2)}{1 + t_2^2t_3^2} = r_3\tag{*2}$$

By brute force, we have
$$s_2 = r_2^2 + r_3^2 + 1 = \frac{(1+t_2^2)(1+t_3^2)}{1+t_2^2t_3^2}
\implies r_2(1+t_2^2) - s_2t_2 = 0
$$
Similarly,
$$s_3 = r_2^2 + r_3^2 - 1 = -\frac{(1-t_2^2)(1-t_3^2)}{
1 + t_2^2t_3^2}
\implies r_3(t_3^2-1) - s_3t_3 = 0$$

Solving these two quadratic equations give us $4$ possible
combinations of $(t_2,t_3)$. Throwing them into an CAS, one
find only two of them, those appear in $(*1)$, satisfy $(*2)$.

Comment: This is sort of what I was looking for. Thank you! I would write a code for  trying and generalising it for any value of r instead of the given combination.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm missing something, but if you substitute $\psi = 0$ in the system, and denote $x = \tan(\theta/2), y = \tan(\phi/2)$, you get the system
$$
\begin{cases}
-xy = r_1 \\ y = r_2\\ x= r_3
\end{cases}.
$$

So, either $r_1 = -r_2 r_3$ and the solution is $(x,y)=(r_3, r_2)$ or you have no solution at all.